# prepareForSegue() not working (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

was hoping to get some help with identifying why my prepareForSegue() is not working.

Here is my Main.storyboard and the identifier for the segue.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFsqF.png

I am linking the Prototype cell as a selection segue (show) to a UITabBarController which will have a few UIViewController connect to it. I have placed breakpoints in the prepareForSegue and see that it never goes into the function, I have a suspicion that I may have setup the segue incorrectly but my inexperience in iOS development is causing me to overlook what the problem is.

Here is my prepareForSegue on my prepareForSegue() on my MainViewController

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showLesson" {
        var tabBarVC: UITabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController
        var descVC: LessonsDetailsViewController = tabBarVC.viewControllers?.first as LessonsDetailsViewController
        var row = tableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
        var dataObj = lessonsNSMObj[row]
        descVC.managedObject = dataObj
    }
}
```

I did find a work around but I am not sure if that is the appropriate way of doing this or if there is downfall of doing it this way.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showLesson" {
        var tabBarVC: UITabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController
        var descVC: LessonsDetailsViewController = tabBarVC.viewControllers?.first as LessonsDetailsViewController
        var row = sender as Int
        var dataObj = lessonsNSMObj[row]
        descVC.managedObject = dataObj
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let row = indexPath.row
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showLesson", sender: row)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciative! I also have the whole project available on github: https://github.com/schuob/

Comment: So the problem isn't that your prepareForSegue() function isn't being called when a segue is performed, but that the segue you want to perform from the table view cell prototype is not occurring.  I've never done that, or worked much with prototype cells, so I can't provide you an answer in the short term. Perhaps someone else can help.  But you might not want to 'bury the lead' as they say, and edit your question to get right to the core issue as fast as possible :-)

Comment: If you linked the segue from the cell, you should not be calling performSegue in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. The sender argument in prepareForSegueWithIdentifier:sender: will be the cell, so you can use the table view method indexPathForCell: to get the indexPath.

Comment: But he said the func is not being called at all. I agree he should not be doing the segue from didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but that is kind of beside the point, because the key to solving this is getting the cell-originated segue to work.

Comment: I downloaded your GitHub code and when I run it I get fatal error (array index out of range) in the line "let lessonObj = lessonsNSMObj[indexPath.row]" of the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" function in the MainViewController.

Comment: 1s and 0s thanks for the feedback, I'll clean up the question once I get to a computer rather then an iPad.

Comment: @rdelmar - sorry if I wasn't clear, I am not doing performSegue in my original code only did that in the work around which seem to work. If I could figure out why it isn't working I would follow the recommendation of not using performSegue.

Comment: @SyedTariq - im sorry I may have forgotten to in the sample SQLite file I am using in my project. I will add that once I can get back to my laptop.

Comment: @rdelmar - so would something like this fire in this scenario if I select the cell? override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        println("test")
    }

Comment: It should if you made the segue from the cell (not the controller). The segue should be executed without the need of any code, and prepareForSegue should be called.

Comment: @rdelmar I'll try it again later tonight, I did make the segue from the cell to the UITabbedViewController and gave it an identifier so not sure if there is any other setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after looking at your code, I found the problem. You're registering the class in viewDidLoad, and you shouldn't do that when you have a cell in the storyboard that you hooked up to a segue. Registering the class, tells the table view to get its cells from the class's code, not from IB, so the cell in IB that you originate the segue from is not the one you're dequeueing. To fix the problem, just delete that line where you register the class. You should also delete the performSegue line in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, or you'll be trying to segue twice.

You need to change your prepareForSegue to get the indexPath from the cell. The cell will be the sender, so you can do it like so,

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let cell = sender as UITableViewCell
        if segue.identifier == "showLesson" {
            var tabBarVC: UITabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController
            var descVC: LessonsDetailsViewController = tabBarVC.viewControllers?.first as LessonsDetailsViewController
            var row = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row
            var dataObj = lessonsNSMObj[row!]
            descVC.managedObject = dataObj
        }
    }
```

You also need to change the identifier in cellForRowAtIndexPath to  "LessonCell" (with a capital "L") since that's what you called it in the storyboard.

Comment: oh my thank you so much, I did not realize that registering that class again was messing with the segue. It is now working without any performSegueWithIdentifier now.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your use of **prepareForSegue** or **performSegueWithIdentifier**. However you appear to have a bug in your ManagedObject code. I took your code and ran it and was getting errors in the Managed Object access (array index out of range). I commented out the buggy statements and executed the code. The **prepareForSegue** as well as the **performSegueWithIdentifier** both executed as you intended.

I beg to differ in opinion with the comments of rdelmar and '1s and 0s' concerning segue-ing from rows. It is routinely done in several Apple programs I have seen. I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: I really appreciate the test I am assuming you got the index out of range due to the fact that you are missing the SQLite file as mention above. I did see the prepareForSegue and performSegue fired as intend. My original problem was without using performSegue it would not fire and I was concern that there would be an issue with the way I worked around it. I understand that prepareForSegue() should work on its own but I have not been able to accomplish that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're objecting to in my comment. All I said was that if the segue is made form the cell, you shouldn't call performSegue in code, which you shouldn't (just like you shouldn't if a segue is made from a button).

Comment: rdelmar - My apology. I misunderstood your statement.